# Why is my render-pass not transitioning into final layout

Tags: c++, vulkan

I am currently trying to incorporate imgui into my vulkan-application.
So i have two render-passes, one for my 3d-scene, and one for imgui.
In my 3d-renderpass i set `initialLayout` to `undefined` and `finalLayout` to `attachmentOptimal`.
In the imgui-renderpass i set `initialLayout` to `attachmentOptimal` and `finalLayout` to `presentSrcKHR`.
I also create the following subpass-dependencies:
For my 3d-renderpass:

```cpp
  auto dependency = vk::SubpassDependency{};
  dependency.srcStageMask = vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eColorAttachmentOutput;
  dependency.srcAccessMask = (vk::AccessFlags)0;
  dependency.srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
  dependency.dstStageMask = vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eColorAttachmentOutput;
  dependency.dstAccessMask = vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentWrite;
  dependency.dstSubpass = 0;

  auto ui_dependency = vk::SubpassDependency{};
  ui_dependency.srcStageMask =
    vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eColorAttachmentOutput;
  ui_dependency.srcAccessMask = vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentWrite;
  ui_dependency.srcSubpass = 0;
  ui_dependency.dstStageMask =
    vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eColorAttachmentOutput;
  ui_dependency.dstAccessMask = vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentWrite |
                                vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentRead;
  ui_dependency.dstSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
```

and for the imgui-renderPass:

```cpp
  auto dependency = vk::SubpassDependency();

  dependency.srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
  dependency.srcStageMask = vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eColorAttachmentOutput;
  dependency.srcAccessMask = vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentRead |
                               vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentWrite;

  dependency.dstSubpass = 0;
  dependency.dstStageMask = vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eColorAttachmentOutput;
  dependency.dstAccessMask = vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentWrite;

  auto extern_dependeny = vk::SubpassDependency{};

  extern_dependeny.srcSubpass = 0;
  extern_dependeny.srcStageMask =
  vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eColorAttachmentOutput;
  extern_dependeny.srcAccessMask = vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentRead |
                                     vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentWrite;

  extern_dependeny.dstSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
  extern_dependeny.dstStageMask =
  vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eColorAttachmentOutput;

  extern_dependeny.dstAccessMask = vk::AccessFlagBits::eMemoryRead;
```

So i would think that i am correctly defining the dependencies of the render-passes.
However, when i submit the two command-buffers, one for the 3d-scene, one for imgui, the validation-layers tell me:

> VUID-VkPresentInfoKHR-pImageIndices-01296(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: -945112042 - Validation Error: [ VUID-VkPresentInfoKHR-pImageIndices-01296 ] Object 0: handle = 0x55eeaedf2f90, name = present_queue, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_QUEUE; | MessageID = 0xc7aabc16 | vkQueuePresentKHR(): Images passed to present must be in layout VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR or VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHARED_PRESENT_KHR but is in VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL. The Vulkan spec states: Each element of pImageIndices must be the index of a presentable image acquired from the swapchain specified by the corresponding element of the pSwapchains array, and the presented image subresource must be in the VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR layout at the time the operation is executed on a VkDevice (https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/search?q=)VUID-VkPresentInfoKHR-pImageIndices-01296)

Note that i do submit the command-buffers with two signal-semaphores, with the pipeline-stage-flags of `colorAttachmentOutput` and `BottomOfPipe` respectively.

In my call to present, i pass both of these semaphores as wait-semaphores.
Does anyone see an obvious error in my subpass-dependencies that would lead to this incorrect behaviour? If other issues could contribute to this error, which i have not mentioned here, let me know and i will happily provide respective code-sections.

Comment: "*Note that i do submit the command-buffers with two signal-semaphores, with the pipeline-stage-flags of colorAttachmentOutput and BottomOfPipe respectively.*" This does not make sense. Why would you need two semaphores? The two command buffers are being submitted in the same batch, right? So the present should only have to wait on that batch. What is the second semaphore for?

Comment: @NicolBolas Thank you for clarifying that - I may have misunderstood the spec there and was assuming that the individual semaphores would be signaled on completion of the individual command-buffers. I must admit that using two semaphores is also one of my attempts to fix this problem - i used one initially, so at least i can tell that this is not where the issue stems from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was doing something extremely stupid in a part of the code not immediately connected to any of the render-passes.

I basically asked for the ui-related `VkCommandBuffer` of the current frame before retrieving the index for the new frame. This meant that I re-recorded, and re-submitted a `VkCommandBuffer` which had not finished executing the rendering of the ui for the previous frame.

This also triggered the following validation-error, which at first I did not take to be immediately connected to the issue (probably stupid in hindsight)

> VUID-vkResetCommandPool-commandPool-00040(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: -1254218959 - Validation Error: [ VUID-vkResetCommandPool-commandPool-00040 ] Object 0: handle = 0x55f944a47040, name = ui_cmd_buffer_0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER; | MessageID = 0xb53e2331 | Attempt to reset command pool with VkCommandBuffer 0x55f944a47040[ui_cmd_buffer_0] which is in use. The Vulkan spec states: All VkCommandBuffer objects allocated from commandPool must not be in the pending state (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.148.0/linux/1.2-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-vkResetCommandPool-commandPool-00040)
> Objects: 1
> [0] 0x55f944a47040, type: 6, name: ui_cmd_buffer_0

So i guess the takeaway is:
If you are sure that the subpass-dependencies, and the specifications of `initialLayout` and `finalLayout` of your render-passes are fine, look at other parts of your code related to `vkQueueSubmit` and `vkQueuePresentKHR`, which might cause the trouble.

In my case it was a re-submitted `VkCommandBuffer`, but problems in your fences or semaphores (trying to render to a swapchain-image that is still presented from/ rendered to by a previous frame) may also lead to such problems.

If you get multiple validation-errors it is probably not a bad idea to assume a relation between them, and try to identify which error might cause another one.